# Issue on Replacing Spaces with Underscores in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can you please let me know how I can replace spcae between names with "`_`" what I have is

```
var name  = $('input[name="name"]').val(); 
$('#nameDiv').html(name.replace(/\s+/g," "));
```

But not doing the job?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to have `_` as the result, use `"_"` instead of `" "` as the second argument to `.replace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this expression:

```
  var name  = $('input[name="name"]').val(); 
  $('#nameDiv').html(name.replace(/_/g, ' '));
```

**Or**

Simply replace `_` with `" "`

```
var name  = $('input[name="name"]').val(); 
$('#nameDiv').html(name.replace("_", ' '));
```

And to change in reverse order

```
 var name  = $('input[name="name"]').val(); 
 $('#nameDiv').html(name..replace(/ /g,"_"));
```

[**Js Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P363R/) // "_" to " "

[**Another Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P363R/1/) // " " to "_"

Comment: Hi Dhaval, thanks but i need to do the opposite way I mean i want to change space to _

Comment: @Behseini Then you can try it's reverse with `.replace(/ /g,"_");`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do it with .replace(/\s+/g, "_")

Answer (score 0):

Actually the main issue you have that you are getting the value of the attribute incorrectly.  Instead, do this

```
 var name = $('input[name="name"]').attr("name"); 
 $('#nameDiv').html(name.replace("_", " "));
```